# Randomly Generating Low-Poly Terrain

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to randomly generate terrain in a low-poly style similar to the terrain seen in [Cube Slam](http://cubeslam.com) and [this video](http://vimeo.com/69335531).  I tried experimenting with the webgl_geometry_terrain.html example, but it still generates somewhat smooth terrain, as opposed to the flat polygons making up my intended terrain.

I'm just starting with Three.js so it's quite possible that there is a rather simple solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_geometry_terrain.html it seems to do pretty good random terrain.

Comment: I referenced a very similar example above (webgl_geometry_terrain.html).  They're both basically the same except my example uses WebGL.  What I'm trying to do is eliminate the path smoothing and have it just generate terrain with flat, straight polygons, like the two examples.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this? I am experimenting with three.js and am trying to go for a similar low poly effect. I was able to get the terrapin draw using a flat color by altering their generateTerrain function but am trying to get the faces shaded based on their angle to the light. Were you ever able to find other resources?

Comment: @RickyHartmann just in case you never solved this, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Really simple, just use `THREE.FlatShading` (edit: and `geometry.computeFaceNormals()`):

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xdddddd, shading: THREE.FlatShading } );
geometry.computeFaceNormals(); // <-- I think you'll need this if you're doing terrain (as opposed to built in geometry like BoxGeometry)
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add(mesh);
```